# Enforce Single User Session - ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

Using the `ss-pid` in ServiceStack session cookies, I am trying to enforce a single user session for a give unique user id.

I am able to persist the ServiceStack session id, when the User logs in.

When the users Bearer Token expires and the Refresh Token is used I would like to check if their session id against what is in my persistence and throw an exception, if the user has a new session id, from logging in on a different device etc.

My problem is that I do not see a way, using the ServiceStack framework, to get the current `ss-pid` value, included in the access-token request. I see that an `access-token` request from an API that has a RefreshToken includes the `ss-pid` cookie in the request:

[image]

I am have implemented `IUserSessionSource`, documentation [here](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#requires-user-auth-repository-or-iusersessionsource), to hydrate the and BearerToken and that method only receives the `userAuthId`.

I have looked through other available methods in `IAuthProvider`, `IsAuthorized` is not called. I thought that `Validate` in `AuthUserSession` could help me to short circuit the authorization but that method does not even seem to be part of `AuthUserSession` anymore and its signature in the [documentation](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#session-events) is not virtual anyways:

```
IHttpResult Validate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, 
    IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo);
```

How to I get the `ss-pid` from an access-token request so I can short circuit the request based on custom logic?

**------------------UPDATE--------------------**

I have found this way to get the `ss-pid`:

```
    public IAuthSession GetUserSession(string userAuthId)
    {
        IRequest req = HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest();
        IAuthSession session = req.GetSession();
    }
```

I guess this is appropriate and not a hacky solution?

Answer (score 0):

All methods on [AuthUserSession are virtual](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/3a18b9f93257a97a1c72d3b41d8b885eef15706f/src/ServiceStack/AuthUserSession.cs#L63-L107).

[JWT's are stateless](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#jwt-overview), their session is encapsulated in the JWT BearerToken. I wouldn't try to add your own Session cookies in addition as it's in conflict with the Session extracted from the JWT BearerToken. If you want save metadata on Authentication save it in the cache or database yourself using your own model instead of trying to create your own UserSession when using stateless Auth Providers like JWT.

Comment: I do not understand how I am supposed to enforce a single user session using JWTs, should I not have used JWTs in the first place since there is a requirement to enforce a single user session?

Comment: I guess there is no way to revoke a single bearer token, you can only revoke all "sessions" for a user id https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11897774

Comment: @BrianOgden Using JWT's are fine, but they're suppose to be stateless. If you need additional metadata about a user you can fetch it as needed using the UserId in the JWT (e.g. from session.UserAuthId). If you want to maintain the metadata save it in a cache yourself using your own models/cache key, i.e. don't try to re-use the session/cookies as the session is extracted from the JWT Token.